# Cannot copy file from external disk to laptop

Tags: windows-7, security, external-hard-drive, permissions, ntfs

I have an external hard drive which contains many files copied from another PC running XP. While I was copying files from this external disk to a laptop running 64 bit Windows 7 I got errors that I needed Everyone permission to copy the files.

The strange thing is that the error occurred for about 20 files only while all other thousands of files were copied successfully. All these files that cannot be copied are exe files but I can copy other executables. It just happens with very small number of exe files.
The external drive is formatted as FAT32 and there is not any security tab to change file permissions.

Also, I am planning to format the drive as NTFS because I will need to copy large files. Will I have any problems accessing these files from another computer if I format the drive as NTFS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if you reformat the hard drive you will lose any files that are currently stored on there.

You need to plug the hard drive back into the original XP computer and reset the permissions on the problem files from there.

If you have [Simple File Sharing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304040) turned on then you won't see a Security tab. Turn it off (the instructions are on the linked page) and then you should be OK to give Everybody rights to those files/folders.